# .NET List not saved to db?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want an item to have several sales linked to it:

```
Sale.cs
```

```
public class Sale
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
```

```
Item.cs
```

```
    public class Item
    {
        [Key]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Market { get; set; }
        public string Market_api { get; set; }
        public List<Sale> Sales { get; set; }
    }
```

I save Sales like this:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Sale(SaleViewModel vm, string name)
        {
            Item item = _repo.GetItem(name);
            item.Sales = item.Sales ?? new List<Sale>();
            item.Sales.Add(new Sale
            {
                Amount = vm.Amount,
                Price = vm.Price
            });

            _repo.UpdateItem(item);

            await _repo.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

```
_repo:
```

```
        public void UpdateItem(Item item)
        {
            _ctx.Items.Update(item);
        }

        public async Task<bool> SaveChangesAsync()
        {
            if(await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync() > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

and when I debug this it all looks good (List is in item) 
[Debug information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvmEG.png) 
[Peek into db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N4vg.png) 
but when I try to access it like:
item.Sales it always returns null. I honestly don't know what's going on, I can see that the correct foreign key is saved in the Sales table but as to why I can't access it I have no clue.

Comment: at `_repo.GetItem(name);`, did u included Sales like `_ctx.Items.Where(f => f. Name == name).Include(i => i.Sales);`

Comment: Thank you so much that was it. Although I needed to modify it a little bit to work:
`return _ctx.Items.Include(i => i.Sales).FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == name);` \ 
Do you mind adding this as an answer?

Comment: glad to help.. I will add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include Sales in your repo get items method

> _repo.GetItem(name);

```
_ctx.Items.Include(i => i.Sales).FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == name);
```